# Which one should i use in spark sql for better performance, either reading the data from Parquet file or reading data from database?

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

Now I m beginner in spark sql (in scala lang). I want to run queries. Does using parquet file really boost performance? Does parquet file or reading data from database(Oracle) need to be placed in HDFS for executing spark queries? which one is the correct way to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One I can say for sure, reading parquet files from HDFS is more scalable comparing to reading RDBMS like Oracle through JDBC connector. And the reason for that is data locality - if your run your Spark executors on the same hosts, where HDFS data nodes located and can effectively read data into memory without network overhead.
See https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/content/spark-data-locality.html
and 
[How does Apache Spark know about HDFS data nodes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28481693/how-does-apache-spark-know-about-hdfs-data-nodes)
for more details.

Also, Parquet format is columnar, and has advantages over traditional RDBMS as OLAP storage (especially when data is sparse). Short comparation: https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Column-oriented_DBMS#/Benefits

Comment: Parquet files by FAR are faster to read than from a DB -- like 3-4 orders of magnitude faster.